# Acquiring a lock on Google BigQuery Table Schema or rejecting schemas not backwards compatible

Tags: multithreading, google-bigquery

Is there a way to acquire a lock on a table schema, and/or to reject table schema `updates|patches` that are not backwards compatible?

I have a distributed application where isolated processes can write to the same bigquery table. Schemas only change in a backwards compatible manner. If a message handled by a process yields a new schema version, the process will patch the target table. However, I never want to patch a schema with a lower version during a race condition.

Ideal scenario looks like this:

- acquire a lock on the table's schema

  - if the table's current schema is of a lesser version than the latest schema, and/or is not a superset of the latest schema fields, then replace the current schema with the latest schema.
  - if the current schema is a later version than the latest schema in that actor's memory, then pull down the current schema and promote.
- release the lock so that other actors can acquire and repeat process

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell you - BigQuery will not allow you to patch table with backward incompatible schema. You will be getting error saying that either specific field is missing or type is changed or something similar.

In BigQuery you can only add new columns to the end of either table or record. I might be missing some specific details but high level it should be correct and should address your concerns I think.

In addition to above want to note that BigQuery is tailored for interactive analysis of massive datasets and less designed to address transaction specific subjects like locking